# ios converting ipad app to universal showing this error nib but the view outlet was not set

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have iPad app and it's working great. I'm trying to convert the app to universal app.

1.- In the summary of the app I change it from iPad to Universal
2.-I add it a nib for the iPhone iPhoneView.xib
3.-in my app delagate I add this code:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
}
else
{

    self.viewController=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"iPhoneView" bundle:nil];
}
```

4.-in the iPhone nib I add viewcontroller as custom class

I run the app using the simulator and I got this error:

```
[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "iPhoneView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

I search for a way to fix and seems like I need the reference outlets to the nib but when I try to drag the connection from the "New Referencing Outlet" on the right side of xcode in the last tab to the nib I can not make the connection or if I try to drag the connection from the view icon to the files owner I can not make the connection neither. Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong?

I'll really appreciate you help.

Comment: go your xib file right click on view connect view to file's owner
Let me know if you not getting my point!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to the iPhoneView.xib first set file owner to your view controller
[image]

After that click on the file owner(yellow block ) and click on the right most arrow in following picture. set all the connections . This will solve your problem.(Probably i think your view is not set to view outlet)